# HP Server attention light is blinking?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-ux, warning

We have an older HP Server RP2470 running HP UX. I've been assigned to perform some hard drive clean up and OS Maintenance on the server before we move it into production.

Everything is going just fine with the OS, so far I haven't noticed anything unusual. However when I went into the systems room to see the server from close, **I've noticed that the attention light on the front of the chassis is blinking yellow.**

[image: HP RP 2470]

**Can anyone tell me what could that indicate?** As i mentioned I haven't noticed anything unusual while working on the server, it is just now when I know this, it is freaking me out.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
Just as a comparison, we have another same server that is already into production and it is not blinking, so I can 100% be sure that this is not normal behavior.

Comment: The HP [A-Class Users Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00044188/c00044188.pdf) (PDF, see page 63) from [this support page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DocumentIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&contentType=SupportManual&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=2511789) indicates the three lights are (from left-to-right) Lan, Heartbeat and power.  You must use all three to determine the fault, if any.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to give RTFM answers here but this questions just screams out for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The light is saying, "I need your attention".

I'd check the power supplies, internal fans and such. If you have console access, get into the GSB and type `Ctrl-B` to check the error logs. Viewing the logs may turn off the light alone. Look for any anomalies in the messages, though.

Comment: lol at "I need your attention".

Comment: Well now it definitely has my attention...